# Excel VBA delete duplicates keep positioning

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

Could someone please help me with some code to delete all duplicate entries across multiple columns and rows. Any cell which has a duplicate value I'd like to be blank, but I do not want to delete the cell and shift all the rows up like the remove duplicates button does. I'd like code exactly like conditional formatting does to highlight cells,  but I'd like to set the value to "" instead.

I'm trying to edit the macro I recorded to something like:

```
Columns("I:R").Select
    selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
    selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
    selection.FormatConditions(1).Value = ""
```

But I'm not sure I'm on the right track

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two sets of nested loops I check each cell in the range twice, once to see if it was a duplicate and to mark it and a second time to then remove the value (ensuring I remove all duplicates and do not leave one instance of each duplicate).

I'm sure that this is an inefficient way of doing it but it works so hopefully helps someone else in the same boat.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Column As Integer

Row = 100
Column = 10

'loop through identifying the duplicated by setting colour to blue
For i = 1 To Row 'loops each row up to row count
    For j = 1 To Column 'loops every column in each cell
        If Application.CountIf(Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(Row, Column)), Cells(i, j)) > 1 Then 'check each cell against entire range to see if it occurs more than once
            Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbBlue 'if it does sets it to blue
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'loop through a second time removing the values in blue (duplicate) cells
For i = 1 To Row 'loops each row up to row count
    For j = 1 To Column 'loops every column in each cell
        If Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = vbBlue Then 'checks if cell is blue (i.e duplicate from last time)
            Cells(i, j) = "" 'sets it to blank
            Cells(i, j).Interior.Color = xlNone 'changes colour back to no fill
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Start at the bottom and work towards the top. Take a ten-column-conditional [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) of the cell values while shortening the rows examined by 1 every loop.

```
Sub clearDupes()
    Dim rw As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With Intersect(.Range("I:R"), .UsedRange)
            .Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            For rw = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
                With .Resize(rw, .Columns.Count)  'if clear both then remove this
                    If Application.CountIfs(.Columns(1), .Cells(rw, 1), .Columns(2), .Cells(rw, 2), _
                                            .Columns(3), .Cells(rw, 3), .Columns(4), .Cells(rw, 4), _
                                            .Columns(5), .Cells(rw, 5), .Columns(6), .Cells(rw, 6), _
                                            .Columns(7), .Cells(rw, 7), .Columns(8), .Cells(rw, 8), _
                                            .Columns(9), .Cells(rw, 9), .Columns(10), .Cells(rw, 10)) > 1 Then

                        'test with this
                        .Rows(rw).Cells.Interior.Color = vbRed
                        'clear values with this once it has been debugged
                        '.Rows(rw).Cells.ClearContents
                    End If
                End With  'if clear both then remove this
            Next rw
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

I've left some code in that only marks the potential duplicates. When you are happy with the results, change that to the commented code that actually clear the cell contents.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. I'm looking to delete every cell which appears more than once. (not necessarily whole rows). I need to be left with only the unique cell values . (i.e. if a cells duplicates then I don't want it at all after running the code, not even once). But I like the countifs. I could perhaps loop through colouring every cell which duplicates then loop again removing then coloured cells. I assume there is no simpler built in  'duplicates' method I'm missing

Comment: That doesn't sound difficult. Just remove the resizing of the range being examined. fwiw, that isn't actually how a [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) works but I guess it is closer to a CF rule for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional format to highlight duplicates and then change the value to "" using a loop through selection.
This code will allow one value to remain.(if you have 25 twice, this code will keep one 25)

```
Option Explicit

Sub DupRem()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim rn As Range
Dim dup As Range
Columns("I:R").FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
Columns("I:R").FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
Columns("I:R").FormatConditions(1).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

For Each rn In Columns("I:R").Cells

If rn <> "" Then
   If rn.DisplayFormat.Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
     If dup Is Nothing Then
     Set dup = rn
     Else
     Set dup = Union(dup, rn)
     End If
   End If
End If
Next
dup.ClearContents
Columns("I:R").FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Columns("I:R").FormatConditions.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Keashan. Unfortunately If a cell duplicates then I don't want it there are all (not even once). if you highlight an array and apply conditional formatting highlight duplicates then it flags all the cells I'd like converted to blanks, but if you then loop through and delete them the last occurrence of duplicates will no longer appear to be a duplicate (as all other occurrences will have been deleted but then). Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply because I was away for few days. I have edited the answer to align with your requirement.